# Translating text with variable in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: translation, prestashop-1.7

When trying to translate the string `There is %product_count% item in your cart.` to `Il y a %products_count% article dans votre panier`, I get `Il y a %products_count% article dans votre panier` in the frontend. It's like `%products_count%` is seen as a string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your template:

```
{l s='There is %s item in your cart.' sprintf=[$product_count] mod='mymodule'}
```

Comment: Please try to give proper explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this in your template:
>
> ```
> {l s='There is %s item in your cart.' sprintf=[$product_count] mod='mymodule'}
> ```

- s=" " - put your text to translate
- %s - your translation variable
- sprintf=[$your_variable] - your variable that will show up in your
  string
- mod='mymodule' - name of your module

After you do that log into your backoffice and do the following steps:

- Go to the “Translations” page under the “International” menu,
- In the “Modify translations” section, find the “Type of translation”
  drop-down and select “Installed modules translations”,
- Choose the module you want to translate. (name in expample is "mymodule" change it to whatever your module name is)
- Choose the language you want to translate the module into. The
  destination language must already be installed to enable translation
  in it.
- Click the “Modify” button.

After completing these steps presta should generate "translatioins" file in your module.

Source:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/module-translation/classic-system/